# Embedding YouTube video with new iframe embed code in TinyMCE

Tags: php, cakephp, youtube, tinymce

I tried the old embed code for adding YouTube videos into TinyMCE and it works fine. Some of the users may not realise they have to click on the old embed code option in YouTube embed code link to add it in.

I want to make it easy for users and allow them to just copy the new embed code directly and paste it on TinyMCE and away they go.

The new embed code looks like the following example:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" 
        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VvJ037b_kLs" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How do I get TinyMCE to accept the new version of the YouTube embed code with iframe?

I'm working on a CakePHP site build.

Comment: can you give us the new embed code?

Comment: lmao, john... you want your question answered you should give all the information people request. why should someone else go and do research to answer your question?

Comment: dogmatic69, honestly, did you read the question "TITLE" ?? I've updated the body content.

Comment: Thariama, sorry I think I misunderstood your statement as you misinterpreted mine! I meant I "reckon" how nice it'd be if users are able to post directly the new embed code from `youtube` without clicking on the old embed code option, while posting in my website. I'm still looking for the answer.

Answer (score 9):

I think that the use of "extended_valid_elements" is better than edit the original settings.

See that: [TinyMCS - extended_valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:extended_valid_elements)

Answer (score 8):

By default TinyMCE will filter out iframe tag for security reasons. You can add this tag and its attributes to the allowed list of html elements.

See http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements

**Default rule set:**

```
tinyMCE.init({
        // ... other configurations
        valid_elements : "@[id|class|style|title|dir<ltr?rtl|lang|xml::lang|onclick|ondblclick|"
+ "onmousedown|onmouseup|onmouseover|onmousemove|onmouseout|onkeypress|"
+ "onkeydown|onkeyup],a[rel|rev|charset|hreflang|tabindex|accesskey|type|"
+ "name|href|target|title|class|onfocus|onblur],strong/b,em/i,strike,u,"
+ "#p,-ol[type|compact],-ul[type|compact],-li,br,img[longdesc|usemap|"
+ "src|border|alt=|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align],-sub,-sup,"
+ "-blockquote,-table[border=0|cellspacing|cellpadding|width|frame|rules|"
+ "height|align|summary|bgcolor|background|bordercolor],-tr[rowspan|width|"
+ "height|align|valign|bgcolor|background|bordercolor],tbody,thead,tfoot,"
+ "#td[colspan|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|bgcolor|background|bordercolor"
+ "|scope],#th[colspan|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|scope],caption,-div,"
+ "-span,-code,-pre,address,-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-h6,hr[size|noshade],-font[face"
+ "|size|color],dd,dl,dt,cite,abbr,acronym,del[datetime|cite],ins[datetime|cite],"
+ "object[classid|width|height|codebase|*],param[name|value|_value],embed[type|width"
+ "|height|src|*],script[src|type],map[name],area[shape|coords|href|alt|target],bdo,"
+ "button,col[align|char|charoff|span|valign|width],colgroup[align|char|charoff|span|"
+ "valign|width],dfn,fieldset,form[action|accept|accept-charset|enctype|method],"
+ "input[accept|alt|checked|disabled|maxlength|name|readonly|size|src|type|value],"
+ "kbd,label[for],legend,noscript,optgroup[label|disabled],option[disabled|label|selected|value],"
+ "q[cite],samp,select[disabled|multiple|name|size],small,"
+ "textarea[cols|rows|disabled|name|readonly],tt,var,big"
});
```

add the following to the end of the list

```
,iframe[src|title|width|height|allowfullscreen|frameborder]
```

**I would not recommend to allow users to embed iframe tag in a public website.**

Comment: Hi thanks !..but what kind of security threat does `iframe` impose ?

Comment: Links to iframe hack:

[Google search for iframe hack](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=security+and+iframe+tag#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=iframe+hack&cp=9&qe=aWZyYW1lIGhh&qesig=77k5N5TLYvv7OgCu1Kfapg&pkc=AFgZ2tnmeFLdWVvhjE13Jum5Gh_Y6X4Xt-C-0ijNRknaDKrrbkRYA8AAgniYYR3oSwTymyEoyUwzxvONyo422ow3ExVPcewDNw&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=iframe+ha&pbx=1&bav=on.1,or.&fp=a66566127318a88c)

[Iframe Hack](http://blog.unmaskparasites.com/2009/04/29/another-type-of-iframe-hack-php-exploit/)