# tinymce - cannot embed video

Tags: asp.net, video, youtube, tinymce

this is **NOT** a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989039/latest-tinymce-how-to-embed-youtube-video-with-new-embed-code-iframe-in-cakeph).

I am developing an application in asp.net and using tinymce. In my application I need to give the user the ability to add his own videos from youtube. From some reason I can embed a video, but it doesn't render. Instead I see this html:

```
<img src="http://localhost/myApplication/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/img/trans.gif" class="mceItemMedia mceItemFlash" width="350" height="300" data-mce-json="{'video':{},'params':{'wmode':'transparent','src':'http://www.youtube.com/v/GEZwVa98oKs&amp;rel=1'}}">
```

Why don't I see my object tags? 
An interesting thing though, When I click the preview button (I enabled that widget), then the video is presented just fine.

What could be causing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

make sure your object tags are to be found inside the [valid_elements](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) or [extended_valid_elements.](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aextended_valid_elements)

Comment: Thank you, but they tags are already specified there. Still, no help

Comment: what do users put into the editor to embed a video? (this way i might be able to identify what is missing)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, needed to add to valid_elements img[*], ifame[*].
Hope tinymce will fix it. I dont want to have iframe in my valid elements!